# Save the output result of a Java program into a file

Tags: java, ubuntu, save, output, logfile

I want to run a so called *Vanity Generator* on my Ubuntu VPS to generate a custom address. The problem is: You start the program with `java genacc` and after this you have to enter a *target* (the custom string you want in your generated address). So after the program starts it asks for the string and then you can't use `CustomString > logfile.txt` because the script would think I want to generate an address which contains `CustomString > logfile.txt` and that doesn't work.

> 1) download  http://blockexplore.in/static/nemGenVanity.zip
>
> 2) unzip to your desktop
>
> 3) open a command prompt and type cd Desktop/nemGenVanity
>
> 4) then type java genacc
>
> 5) pick the target that you would like in your address
>
> Three letter words should come really fast, four letter still quickly, five letter words might take a some minutes, six letter words might take some hours, and seven letter words will take days.

README.txt

> To Run: java genacc
>
> To compile from source: javac genacc.java
>
> Creates accounts until it finds your target string. If someone has the > private key, they have your account. So keep it safe.
>
> General remark on addresses:
>
> 1) All mainnet addresses start with a 'N' followed by 'A', 'B', 'C', or 'D'. So you won't find addresses that start with 'NE' or 'NN' or 'N4'.
>
> 2) The digits '0', '1', '8' and '9' are not part of base32 and therefore will not appear in any address.

Answer (score 1):

It is slightly unclear exactly how you use this from the description, so I'll cover two likely scenarios.

Case 1: The Java program genacc reads from standard input.  That is, if you were to simply run it interactively, you'd type something like the following

```
java genacc
MyCustomAddress
```

followed by a control-D character (indicating "end of file" on input from a terminal), where `MyCustomAddress` is a line of input to the program.

If that is the case, simply use the `>` character on the command to write its standard output to your log file, thus:

```
java genacc > logfile.txt
MyCustomAddress
```

Case 2: If `MyCustomAddress` is a command line parameter to be passed into the Java program (thus, in its `main(String [] args)` element [0]), interactively like this:

```
java genacc MyCustomAddress
```

then simply add the redirection to the end of the command

```
java genacc MyCustomAddress > logfile.txt
```

The program *will not* "see" the `>` or the file name following.  These are interpreted by the shell.  Internally, the shell does magic to assign the standard output file descriptor to `logfile.txt` before invoking java, passing it only the `MyCustomAddress` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
nohup java genacc <<< "test" >> log.txt &
```

This will start the generator and you can escape with `ctrl+x`. After the program generated an address the result shows up in the log.txt

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You're welcome.  FYI, there is also a construct called a "here file" that can be used in such a case.  It is particularly useful if the input is more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pipe?

```
java genacc | > logfile.txt
```

Comment: Nope. It seems that the program doesn't make a cut. It thinks that I want a pipe within the generated address. And you got s.th. wrong. You start the program with `java genacc` and after this you have to input the custom string you want in your address generated by the program. And this result I want to save. So I ran the programm with `java genacc` and typed in `MyString | > log.txt` but that doesn't work, because it thinks that the pipe and > log.txt is the content of my string.

Comment: Did you mean to pipe through tee?  (i.e. java genacc | tee logfile.txt); this will have the effect of writing to the logfile  but also to stdout (so you can see the prompts)